# Adding auto play to Javascript image slider

Tags: javascript

I have a slider and I want to add auto play every 3 seconds. I tried to use SetInterval but nothing happened.

Also I would like to remove the code for removing elements from the slider. I want to remove all the controls also and have only the slider changing image every 3 seconds.

this is the slider code

```js
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
const galleryControlsContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-controls');
const galleryControls = ['Предидущий', '', 'Следующий'];
const galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

class Carousel {
  constructor(container, items, controls) {
    this.carouselContainer = container;
    this.carouselControls = controls;
    this.carouselArray = [...items];
  }

  updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });

    this.carouselArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
      el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
  }

  setCurrentState(direction) {

    if (direction.className == 'gallery-controls-previous') {
      this.carouselArray.unshift(this.carouselArray.pop());
    } else {
      this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    }
    
    this.updateGallery();
  }


  setControls() {
    this.carouselControls.forEach(control => {
      galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;

      document.querySelector(`.gallery-controls-${control}`).innerText = control;
    });
  }
 
  useControls() {
    const triggers = [...galleryControlsContainer.childNodes];

    triggers.forEach(control => {
      control.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (control.className == 'gallery-controls-add') {
          const newItem = document.createElement('img');
          const latestItem = this.carouselArray.length;
          const latestIndex = this.carouselArray.findIndex(item => item.getAttribute('data-index') == this.carouselArray.length)+1;

          Object.assign(newItem,{
            className: 'gallery-item',
            src: `http://fakeimg.pl/300/?text=${this.carouselArray.length+1}`
          });
          newItem.setAttribute('data-index', this.carouselArray.length+1);

          this.carouselArray.splice(latestIndex, 0, newItem);
          document.querySelector(`[data-index="${latestItem}"]`).after(newItem);
          this.updateGallery();

        } else {
          this.setCurrentState(control);
        }

      });
    });
  }
}

const exampleCarousel = new Carousel(galleryContainer, galleryItems, galleryControls);

exampleCarousel.setControls();
exampleCarousel.useControls();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code, I have added auto slide functionality with interval time 5 seconds.

If you want to change the interval, Please update the `setInterval` time in the "constructor" and "setCurrentState" functions.

I have removed the controls. To remove the controls, we need to comment the last 2 lines

> //exampleCarousel.setControls();
>
> //exampleCarousel.useControls();

```js
const galleryContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-container');
const galleryControlsContainer = document.querySelector('.gallery-controls');
const galleryControls = ['Предидущий', '', 'Следующий'];
const galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

class Carousel {
  constructor(container, items, controls) {
    this.carouselContainer = container;
    this.carouselControls = controls;
    this.carouselArray = [...items];
    this.mySlideInterval = null;
    this.mySlideInterval = setInterval(
        this.autoSlide.bind(this),
        5000
    );
  }

  autoSlide() {
    this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    this.updateGallery();
  }
  
  updateGallery() {
    this.carouselArray.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-1');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-2');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-3');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-4');
      el.classList.remove('gallery-item-5');
    });

    this.carouselArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((el, i) => {
      el.classList.add(`gallery-item-${i+1}`);
    });
  }

  setCurrentState(direction) {

    if (direction.className == 'gallery-controls-previous') {
      this.carouselArray.unshift(this.carouselArray.pop());
    } else {
      this.carouselArray.push(this.carouselArray.shift());
    }
    
    clearInterval(this.mySlideInterval);
    this.updateGallery();
    this.mySlideInterval = setInterval(
        this.autoSlide.bind(this),
        5000
    );
  }


  setControls() {
    this.carouselControls.forEach(control => {
      galleryControlsContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).className = `gallery-controls-${control}`;

      document.querySelector(`.gallery-controls-${control}`).innerText = control;
    });
  }
 
  useControls() {
    const triggers = [...galleryControlsContainer.childNodes];

    triggers.forEach(control => {
      control.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (control.className == 'gallery-controls-add') {
          const newItem = document.createElement('img');
          const latestItem = this.carouselArray.length;
          const latestIndex = this.carouselArray.findIndex(item => item.getAttribute('data-index') == this.carouselArray.length)+1;

          Object.assign(newItem,{
            className: 'gallery-item',
            src: `http://fakeimg.pl/300/?text=${this.carouselArray.length+1}`
          });
          newItem.setAttribute('data-index', this.carouselArray.length+1);

          this.carouselArray.splice(latestIndex, 0, newItem);
          document.querySelector(`[data-index="${latestItem}"]`).after(newItem);
          this.updateGallery();

        } else {
          this.setCurrentState(control);
        }

      });
    });
  }
}

const exampleCarousel = new Carousel(galleryContainer, galleryItems, galleryControls);

//exampleCarousel.setControls();
//exampleCarousel.useControls();
```